# Copying file into root directory

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, root

I have a .bin file and need to copy it into a directory with root permission on an Ubuntu machine. How to do this operation in Java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html would be a good starting point

Comment: Are you trying to write an Ubuntu Virus in Java?? :D

Comment: Is your Java program executed by the root user or are you asking how to elevate to root within a Java application?

Comment: try "gksu copy foo bar"

Comment: for the copying the file itself in Java I would propose using methods in `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` than fiddling with the streams manually...

Comment: @Duncan The jave code is for web based application.

Comment: @jobz That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: A web based application copying a .bin file with root permissions? I know People who would suggest hanging you at the village oak for this. But seriously: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Duncan im not running as root user

Comment: Can you tell me what website / application this is so I can avoid it like the plague? I cannot think of ANY reason for a web app to write to the `/` folder without root permission, nor would I ever want to use a company's product if that is their practice. "How to do this operation in Java?" - DON'T!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

To check if the user name is 'root' and proceed or tell him/her to log in as root and relaunch the application*.

Also you can launch a process from java:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./something.sh");
```

Doing in that script that it copies that file to desired path and with the setuid bit properly setted:

```
chown root:root something.sh
chmod 4755 something.sh
```

You could run it as root.

Anyway usually is not a good idea to write in '/'. Are you sure you want to do it?

- PD: I thought it was an desktop application, not webapplication. User in this case should be always something like 'tomcat'.

Comment: +1 for this method, but the OP's question sounds very dodgy altogether. I'd be ok being told to log in as root, but I'd be seriously never want to use their web app in a million years if (s)he's trying to circumvent basic security!

Comment: Hi all.The scenario is i will be getting a .bin file and to load this into a Device i need to put it into a location where the tftp server is mounted in PC where the web application is running. in order to access the mount point i need always root permission.

Comment: @jobz so you need access to some directory? to do that dont need root access on your webapp, just change the owner/permissions of that directory to give tomcat:tomcat access (maybe you will need to give 'execution' permission to DIRECTORIES -only directories- in path to that directory in order to navigate to it).